# How to transfer the choice of optional packages to a new Ubuntu version?

Tags: apt, package-management, system-installation

Assume we have an older Ubuntu installation that is somehow messed up.
It is to be replaced by a clean installation of the current* Ubuntu version.

On the old setup, there are more packages installed than the packages installed by default.

On a plain new Ubuntu installation, the same optional packages **should be installed, if they still exist in the newer Ubuntu version**.

It would be interesting which packages no longer exist.

The plan is not to transfer actual package files, but only the information which optional packages were installed.

For example, on the old setup, the package `pinfo` was installed. It is an optional package that still exist in the newer version.

It contains the program `pinfo`, which is in the default `PATH`, but that information should not be used, as it should also work for font packages.

An approach to a solution could use that on the old system,
`apt list pinfo` shows

```
pinfo/now 0.6.9-5.1 amd64 [installed,local]
```

and on the new system, it shows

```
pinfo/eoan 0.6.13-1 amd64
pinfo/eoan 0.6.13-1 i386`
```

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>The current version is 19.10, but that should not be relevant. If you think it is, please state that explicitly</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of packages, apt has the following command:

```
apt list [option]
```

Some useful options for your case being...

```
--installed
```

displays packages that are installed on the system

```
--manual-installed
```

lists the packages that were explicitly installed